# Is it possible to dynamically adjust contamination parameter in Isolation Forest?

Tags: python, machine-learning, outliers, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I build an anomaly detection model using Isolation Forest with default setting for the contamination paramter (0.1). It works quite good on my current data set, but now I have different files with the same structure but different row count and once I run the model I don't get accurate results anymore without manually adjusting the contamination parameter through playing around until it fits.

I would like to run the model automatically as soon as I get a new file, but the percentage of outliers in my data varies in each file and it's not possbile to get good results since I always have to change the contamination parameter. Is there a way to calculate a new parameter every time a new file arrives or is this model not suitable for my use case?

Comment: To my knowledge you cant adjust params online, you can however count some average value and use it.

Answer (score 1):

The `contamination` parameter is a hyperparameter. It can be tuned with [hyperparameter optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization). Typical approach in scikit-learn with small models/dataset would be to use gridsearch, see the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html). This assumes that you have a robust quantitive way of evaluating your model performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask you kindly to have a look at related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643736/incorrect-results-of-isolationforest)?

Comment: How would you do a hyper parameter tuning for unsupervised learning ?

Comment: The same way as with supervised learning - using a labeled validation set. The number of labled samples can be quite small and still be immensely useful. 10 or 100 already much better than 0.